# Multiple CAAnimations for animationDidStop method?

Tags: ios, animation, delegates, core-animation

I know you have to use this method to get the delegate method for when the animation has finished:

```
- (void)animationDidStop:(CAAnimation *)theAnimation finished:(BOOL)flag {
```

The problem is, how would I distinguish between multiple CAAnimations like 2 or more?

I googled this and I haven't found anything useful.

Please share with me on how you accomplished this!

Thanks!

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can set key/value objects for CAAnimation instance like this:

```
CABasicAnimation *theAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
[theAnimation setValue:@"animation1" forKey:@"id"]; 
theAnimation.delegate = self;

CABasicAnimation *theAnimation2 = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
[theAnimation2 setValue:@"animation2" forKey:@"id"];    
theAnimation2.delegate = self;
```

Check which one was called in delegate method:

```
- (void)animationDidStop:(CAAnimation *)anim finished:(BOOL)flag{
    if([[anim valueForKey:@"id"] isEqual:@"animation1"]) {
        NSLog(@"animation1");
    }
    if([[anim valueForKey:@"id"] isEqual:@"animation2"]) {
        NSLog(@"animation2");
    }
}
```

Comment: i'm surprised & bummed you can't just do an `if (anim == theAnimation) { ... }` - it would be great for error catching and auto-complete, etc. anyone know why you CANNOT do that? the `anim` value does appear to be set and saved in memory when I NSLog it..

Comment: `theAnimation` is declared as local, you can't access it in animationDidStop. If you declare it as global, then question will be a quite poor since you can access that ivar anywhere

Comment: @toblerpwn when you add an animation to a layer, that animation is copied to that layer instead of being referenced directly. that's why you can not use == operator on animations.

Comment: __Be aware that `CAAnimation`'s `delegate` is strong, so you might need to set it to `nil` to avoid retain cycles!__

Comment: [theAnimation2 setValue:@"animation2" forKey:@"id"]  does not work!!!! And the CABasicAnimation object changed like @akaralar said. Why this is right answer?

Answer (score 1):

A `CAAnimation` object is supposed to be reused from time to time and that's why I don't like to give it a certain key (since it's not unique). What makes it unique is the association with a CALayer with `addAnimation:forKey:`. For this reason I use the following code in `animationDidStop`:

```
if animation == layer.animationForKey(AnimationKeys.scaleUp) {
   // scaleUp animation has completed
}
```

Comment: This *will only work* if you set "animation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false", otherwise the animation is removed from the layer as soon as it finish and you'll never enter in the if statement.