# Stairs of animation animationWithDuration

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uiview

I use `animationWithDuration` for animating elements. An I have 1 animation inserted in `completion` block of another.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 delay:0.1 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{

} completion:^(BOOL finished) {

    [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 delay:0.1 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{

} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
... //and simple

}];
}];
```

So I have Stairs of six - nine elements of blocks of `animationWithDuration`.So how I can optimize this?

Sorry for my English.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7751530/1059705 try this..

Comment: Do they all have the same duration, delay and options?

Comment: @Wain they have different delay and duration

Comment: @Bala i don't see any relations with my question and that answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have many nested animations the code quickly becomes very unreadable.
So the approach here is maybe to hold an array of all animation blocks and to iterate through them without nesting them.

One possible example how this looks in code is shown here:
[Multiple UIView Animations Without Nested Blocks](http://xibxor.com/objective-c/uiview-animation-without-nested-hell/)