# Get UIVIew from CAAnimation

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, caanimation

I am trying to get `UIView` object from `CAAnimation`. I have implemented the following `CAAnimationDelegate` method

```
public func animationDidStop(_ animation:CAAnimation, finished:Bool) {
     // Need respective View from "animation:CAAnimation"
}
```

This class will be performing multiple animations with different views. So I need to find out which View's animation is completed in this delegate method. Please guide me if there is any possibility to get the view from this animation.

Comment: Use Key Value Coding to carry a reference to the view inside the animation.

Comment: Thanks Matt! It works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As matt suggested here is the way you can find which animation has been completed.

First of all you need to add different key value to your animation when you are creating it like shown below:

```
let theAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "opacity")
theAnimation.setValue("animation1", forKey: "id")
theAnimation.delegate = self

let theAnimation2 = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "opacity")
theAnimation2.setValue("animation2", forKey: "id")
theAnimation2.delegate = self
```

And in `animationDidStop` method you can identify animations:

```
func animationDidStop(_ anim: CAAnimation, finished flag: Bool) {

    if let val = anim.value(forKey: "id") as? String {
        switch val {
        case "animation1":
            print("animation1")
        case "animation2":
            print("animation2")
        default:
            break
        }
    }
}
```

I have taken [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7748722/multiple-caanimations-for-animationdidstop-method) answer and converted Objective c code to swift with `switch` case.

Answer (score 0):

I just use tag property in UIView

```
animatedView.tag = 10

func animationDidStop(_ anim: CAAnimation, finished flag: Bool) {
    for myView in view.subviews {
        if myView.tag == 10 {
            myView.removeFromSuperview()
            return
        }
    }
}
```